# How to Facebook Post to friends in Android?

Tags: android, facebook, post

I am new to Android. I would like to post an image to my friend's Wall using Facebook.

I have downloaded code from GitHub source. I logged in my account, say peter@gmail.com and grab all of my friends list and populate all my friends in List View.

I have IDs and names of all friends.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
try{
    Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
    JSONObject attachment = new JSONObject();

    try {
        attachment.put("message", "Messages");
        attachment.put("name", "Get utellit to send messages like this!");
        attachment.put("href", link);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
    }
    parameters.putString("attachment", attachment.toString());
    parameters.putString("message", "Text is lame. Listen up:");
    parameters.putString("target_id", "XXXXX"); // target Id in which you need to Post 
    parameters.putString("method", "stream.publish");
    String  response = authenticatedFacebook.request(parameters);       
    Log.v("response", response);
}
catch(Exception e){}
```

Also check this for Reference [Post on Friends Wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896863/post-on-users-friends-facebook-wall-through-android-application)