# Post on user's friends facebook wall through android application

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-wall

I am developing an **Android** application in which the user logs in using its facebook id.
I can get all the information about the user and i even get its friends list with following methods

facebookClient.request("me")

facebookClient.request("me/friends")

My query is that i want to give flexibility to the user to invite its facebook friends.
I dont know what extra stuff is to be done here.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your question is too general/open.  Please provide in more details which part of the functionality you are having trouble with (code snippets would help too).

Comment: Thanks for commenting Kon. As i mentioned i am developing facebook application and using facebook sdk for android for the user to log in to my app. And as the user logs in i get the token and with that token i can get all information about the user which is present on facebook. I can even get the friends list but now i want to allow the user to post message on its friends walls. More like an invitation to my application. How can i get this working in android.

Comment: Oh, so just the actual wall post part..  gotcha..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out:

[How to post on facebook wall using Facebook android SDK, without opening dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213767/how-to-post-on-facebook-wall-using-facebook-android-sdk-without-opening-dialog-b)

and

[How to post message on facebook wall using Facebook android SDK integrate android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883063/how-to-post-message-on-facebook-wall-using-facebook-android-sdk-integrate-android)

Here's a small example that will post to a friend's wall (or if userId is null then to the currently logged in user's wall):

```
protected void postToWall(String userId)
{
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("message", _messageInput.getText().toString());
    params.putString("caption", "{*actor*} just posted a secret message.");
    params.putString("description", "A secret message is waiting for you.  Click the link to decode it.");
    params.putString("name", "A Secret Message For You");
    params.putString("picture", "http://www.kxminteractive.com/Content/images/app_logos/secretMessage.png");
    params.putString("link", "http://www.kxminteractive.com/decrypt/" + _lookupKey);        

    asyncRunner.request(((userId == null) ? "me" : userId) + "/feed", params, "POST", new WallPostRequestListener());       
}
```

Comment: Great start...  +.5 as is.   I'd give it a full +1 if you'd also provide the code on how to set up the asyncRunner.

Comment: @Kon This is not working now as graph api is not allowed to post on friends wall.Will you please show me how to do this?

Comment: Sunny, this was the answer three years ago. I haven't done much Facebook dev since then.

Comment: is it possible to post massage on friends wall...?

Comment: same question from my side, anyone knows if its currently possible at all? :)

Answer (score 0):

use this to send message on friends wall of id(uid):

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();                           
params.putString("message", "hello ...");
Utility.mAsyncRunner.request(uid+"/feed", params, "POST", new FriendRequestListener(), null);
```