# How can I post text on a friend's wall using the android facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use the Android Facebook sdk to make a post on the user's friend's wall. I have successfully posted to the user's own news feed using similar calls. With my current code, the post to a friend works without a hitch, except that the message is blank. None of the attachments seem to work. It shows up as a completely blank post on the friend's wall.

This is the code I am using:

```
private void publishChallengeToFriend() {
    String description = 
        "I challenge you to " + m_challenge.getTitle() + "!" + 
        " I finished this challenge with a score of " + getScore() + "."
        + " Can you beat that?";

    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString(Facebook.TOKEN, m_facebook.getAccessToken());
    params.putString("message", "");
    params.putString("name", "You have been challenged!");
    params.putString("caption", "Mobile Challenges");
    params.putString("description", description);
    try{
    m_facebook.request(getFriendId() + "/feed",params, "POST");
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Log.d("TAG", "Facebook Error: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

I have already authorized the user, and I know that works because I can post to the user's own feed. I am aware of the github issue #166 at https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/issues/166. I have tried using putByteArray() for each of the attachments by calling getBytes() on each string I would like to transmit. This still shows up as a blank post on the friend's wall.

I am open to using any method of posting on the friend's wall, it doesn't have to be a facebook request. I have also used asyncfacebookrunner.request() and have had the same problem. Ideally, I would like to use a dialog to show this, but I have no idea how to use the dialog() function for friend posts. I use that for status updates without a hitch, however.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are putting the message as the description, try moving it to the message parameter, the "description" parameter is a description of a link that you put in the post and will appear under the link. It wont show on your post because your not linking anything! You can see my method for doing it below:

```
protected void postToWall(String userID){
    try {
        if (isSession()) {
            String response = mFacebook.request((userID == null) ? "me" : userID);

            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString("message", "put message here");
            params.putString("link", "http://mylink.com");    
            params.putString("caption", "{*actor*} just posted this!");
            params.putString("description", "description of my link.  Click the link to find out more.");
            params.putString("name", "Name of this link!");
            params.putString("picture", "http://mysite.com/picture.jpg");

            response = mFacebook.request(((userID == null) ? "me" : userID) + "/feed", params, "POST");       

            Log.d("Tests",response);
            if (response == null || response.equals("") || 
                    response.equals("false")) {
                Log.v("Error", "Blank response");
            }
        } else {
            // no logged in, so relogin
            Log.d(TAG, "sessionNOTValid, relogin");
            mFacebook.authorize(this, PERMS, new LoginDialogListener());
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

this is the result so you can see where the different parameters appear on the post:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! You are definitely on to something, I tried making the message my description instead of the description tag and then the message part was displayed! However, all of the other parameters (name, caption, and even description and link if I define one) still don't show up. All of those parameters worked when I publish to the user's own feed. I want more than just a simple message post on the friend's wall. Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: added more code to my answer plus a pic of what it looks like on the wall so you can see how it looks

Comment: That was very helpful! I followed exactly what you did and it worked! It is so weird, I think the only thing that changed was the order that I added the attachments to the bundle.

Comment: It shouldn't really matter what order you add things to the bundle because when facebook processes the request, they search for the key then extract the value. But the main thing is you got it working!

Comment: That's what I thought...but that's all I changed...Weird! But thanks again for all your help, you're right, it's working!

Answer (score 0):

Check out my answer here: 
[Post on user's friends facebook wall through android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896863/post-on-users-friends-facebook-wall-through-android-application#answer-5898193)

Comment: Thank you! I had looked at that answer several times before I posted this. I have used almost identical code for my application, but, as I stated in a comment on the answer above, none of the parameters show up except the message. I want to use title and caption to make it nicer to look at. Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure getFriendId() returns what you expect, and what is m_facebook?  Have you tried using async runner?

Comment: Yes, I know getFriendId() is working since the blank post I am experiencing goes to the correct user. I have tried using async runner and I get the same results :(. Somehow my attachments aren't being sent properly i guess...

Comment: Hmm.. very strange..  Is it also blank if you post to your own wall?  Have you tried that?  Also, this may be a dumb suggestion, but try to put strings into bundle in same order as I did in my answer.  Also, have you tried not leaving message blank?  Pass something in besides an empty string.

Comment: Thank you! That did it, the order in which I added the parameters to the bundle made all the difference! I have no idea why this would be but that did it. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Heh.. that is strange indeed.  But I'm glad it worked.  :)  Feel free to mark this as answered.  ;)

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow...I liked both of your answers...can I give you both credit somehow?