# post on facebook with description android

Tags: android, facebook

I have used the code from https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk. for facebook status update through app.

The code works fine, but I need to add some description below the post. I am unable to do so. 
I tried:

```
            bundle.putString("message", "this is a demo message");
            bundle.putString("description", "My Game");
            bundle.putString("name", "is playing now...");
```

but it won't post. Has anyone used the same code and faced a problem like this..
please help me....

Answer (score 0):

The description part of the bundle is actually the description of a link, since you have not provided a link the description will not be shown. So... I think you would be best to put the description as part of your message.

You can see an example of what i am saying in my answer to a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480582/how-can-i-post-text-on-a-friends-wall-using-the-android-facebook-sdk/6484093#6484093). Hope this helps!