# How do I post some message on a friend's wall using the Android Facebook SDK?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-friends

```
protected void postToWall(String userID){
try {
    if (isSession()) {
        String response = mFacebook.request((userID == null) ? "me" : userID);

        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("message", "put message here");
        params.putString("link", "some link");    
        params.putString("caption", "{*actor*} just posted this!");
        params.putString("description", "description of my link.  Click the link to find out more.");
        params.putString("name", "Name of this link!");
        params.putString("picture", "some pciture");

        response = mFacebook.request(((userID == null) ? "me" : userID) + "/feed", params, "POST");       

        Log.d("Tests",response);
        if (response == null || response.equals("") || 
                response.equals("false")) {
            Log.v("Error", "Blank response");
        }
    } else {
        // no logged in, so relogin
        Log.d(TAG, "sessionNOTValid, relogin");
        mFacebook.authorize(this, PERMS, new LoginDialogListener());
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();}
```

I'm a bit new in Android. I have successfully done posting in my own wall and I wish to post on my friends' wall through my android mobile app. The above example code fits best for my requirement.

I do not understand where to get the `userID` from (that has to be passed as a string to this method). Please guide me and provide me with something that would give me the IDs of user's friends.

Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480582/how-can-i-post-text-on-a-friends-wall-using-the-android-facebook-sdk) where I found this code. My requirement is exactly the same.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't post to a friends wall

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to request for 'publish_actions' ….
see the below link ::

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.0

Regard's,
S@ki ;)